# How to extract rar file (AppEngineFile) in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore, rar

My application requires extracting rar file in Google App Engine. I can extract rar file using  [this library](https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar) but it only supports java.io.File and does not support AppEngineFile. I can not find any solution to solve this problem. Someone have any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The [junrar](https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar/tree/master/unrar) library says it takes an InputStream, not a file.

You may want to try uploading your rar files to [BlobStore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview) instead of reading from the filesystem. Then you can use [BlobstoreInputStream](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreInputStream) to read the data into unrar.

Note that since you can't write to the filesystem, you'll need to store the unpacked data back into the blobstore or datastore.

Comment: Extracting rar file using junrar must use Archive class. But I can not find any contructor of this class contains InputStream as a parameter. So how can I construct Archive object using InputStream